# Webservice always returns true when validating JSON data

Tags: php, jquery

What I am trying to do is validate whether an email address is in the database or not. My `CheckEmailAddress` checks if the email is in the database and it seems to work(rewrite it if needed). The problem is when I post my JSON email data from my JQuery function it always returns true when there should be a false if the email is entered in the database.

JQUERY:

```
$('#checkemail').click(function() {
    $.post('http://' +  location.host + '/buyme/include/getemailaddress.php', 
        {'email':'test012@yahoo.co.nz'},  function(res){
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);
        alert(obj)
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?PHP
    require_once("membership.php");
    $membership = new Membership();
    $val = $_POST["email"];;
    $result = $membership->CheckEmailAddress(trim($val));
    echo json_encode($result); //output test@test.com   
?>

function CheckEmailAddress($email_address) {
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost:3306','root','')or die('Error connecting');
    mysql_select_db('buyme') or die('Connection not working properly');     
    $query = "SELECT email_address from users where email_address='$email_address'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $emailInUse = 'false';
    if(!$row || $row["email_address"] == '') {
        $emailInUse = 'true';
    }else{
        $emailInUse = 'false';  
    }

    return $emailInUse;
}
```

if anything needs correction please update my code so i can test thanks

UPDATE:

```
    try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=buyme;host=localhost:3306', 'root', '', 
        $options = array (
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
    $email_address = 'kirkdm021@yahoo.co.nz';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email_address
            FROM users 
            WHERE email_address=:email_address");
    $stmt->execute(array('email_address'=>$email_address));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchObject();

    echo empty($rows->email_address) ? "" : $rows->email_address; // $row["email_address"];

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('error: ' . $e->getMessage());      
}
```

Comment: Yeah i will but for now I just want to get my functions working

Comment: I've just started learning PHP so I don't really understand all that.

Comment: Well, first of all, I'm not sure why you're `json_encode`ing the email address before you pass it to your function.

Comment: I don't know much at this point of php if you could correct my mistakes i can learn from it

Comment: Why are you returning `true` when the email address is empty? And, what is the original value of `$emailInUse` variable?

Comment: I got it working if someone knows how to make any corrections to my code please doso so i cn learn from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `TRUE` & `FALSE` assignments are returning strings & not `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. Meaning they will always essentially be seen as `TRUE` because they are strings that contain values. A `FALSE` will always contain nothing. Also, you are doing an `OR` by doing `||` when it should be an `AND` by doing `&&`. So this snippet of code:

```
if(!$row || $row["email_address"] == '') {
    $emailInUse = 'true';
}else{
    $emailInUse = 'false';  
}
```

Should be rewritten like this:

```
if(!$row && $row["email_address"] == '') {
    $emailInUse = TRUE;
}else{
    $emailInUse = FALSE;  
}
```

And the final function would look like this:

```
function CheckEmailAddress($email_address) {
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost:3306','root','')or die('Error connecting');
    mysql_select_db('buyme') or die('Connection not working properly');     
    $query = "SELECT email_address from users where email_address='$email_address'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(!$row && $row["email_address"] == '') {
        $emailInUse = TRUE;
    }else{
        $emailInUse = FALSE;  
    }

    return $emailInUse;
}
```

That said, I would recommend avoiding an `else` statement by doing this:

```
    $emailInUse = FALSE;        
    if(!$row || $row["email_address"] == '') {
        $emailInUse = TRUE;
    }

    return $emailInUse;
```

Might not seem like a big difference, but from my experience, initing values like this with default values saves you headaches in the long run. Might not mean much in this script, but if you are a beginning programmer it’s a habit I recommend you getting into early on.

**EDIT WITH ADDITIONAL PERSPECTIVE:** Also, I just re-read your post.  You seem to want to return the words “true” and “false”? Bad habit. Let the function return a logically `TRUE` or `FALSE` as I explained & then act on it in your main code.  So this coding:

```
<?PHP
    require_once("membership.php");
    $membership = new Membership();
    $val = $_POST["email"];;
    $result = $membership->CheckEmailAddress(trim($val));
    echo json_encode($result); //output test@test.com   
?>
```

Would now look like this:

```
<?PHP
    require_once("membership.php");
    $membership = new Membership();
    $val = $_POST["email"];;
    $result = $membership->CheckEmailAddress(trim($val));
    $result_value = !empty($result) ? 'true' : 'false';
    echo json_encode($result_value); //output test@test.com   
?>
```

See that line that reads `$result_value = !empty($result) ? 'true' : 'false';`? That is an inline bit of code that is an alternative to `if`/`else` stuff for values. I have genuine forgotten the formal name for that method, but it is useful for cases like this. The log flow is basically

```
[value] = [test] ? [test value] : [default value];
```

That basically means if `test` passes, make the value what comes after the `?`. If the test does not pass? then use the default value to the right of the `:`.

Comment: so can I access true and false without json.Parse() on my return value in my jquery

Comment: Thanks for you're input. I made those changes and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

First, the error I see in your code it that you are missing to embed `$email_address` in quotes : `'` when building the SQL query.

But rather fixing the query, I would advice you to use prepared statements. Because a that's most secure against SQL injections and its easy to use.

Here comes an example using the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extendsion:

```
function CheckEmailAddress($email_address) {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', '', $options = array (
             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));

        // prepare a statement 
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
            SELECT `email_address`
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE `email_address`=:email_address
        ');

        $stmt->execute(array(
            'email_address' => $email_address
        ));

        $row = $stmt->fetchObject();

        if(!$row || $row["email_address"] == '') {
            return 'true';
        }else{
            return 'false';  
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // just for debugging. Don't display the error message in
        // production envirionemnet as it can contain sensitive data
        die('error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: is PDO part of MYSQL or is MYSQL

Comment: Have not really understand the question

Comment: I will look into PDO do have any links you could share to get me started with the basics of PDO

Comment: @KDM  Here are some links to help you :  [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Hey man could you give me the steps to installing PDO for php I dont know how todo this I don't know where to begin and what to download

Comment: I installed php mysql and apache with wamp server how do install PDO

Comment: PDO should be installed by default with PHP. Can you post the output of `<?php var_dump(class_exists('PDO')); ?>` ?

Comment: yeah its says boolean true; is that working and instlled. I tried you're code that you posted but it doesn't work with $stmt->fectchObject(); so i tried $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); and it still doesn't work or give me the desired results

Comment: Well it always is show true whien it should also say false; there was an error on the $row = $stmt->fectchObject(); so I changed it to $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); and Im still getting nothing Im not getting false I don't even know if im connecting to the database. I added the php_pdo_msql extension and restarted the service

Comment: Note that PDO runs in Exception mode. If establishing the connection or the query itself would fail, you would see the error message. I'm using `try / catch`. `fetchObject()` will work too. It was just a typo.

Comment: Well im having a problem in the if(!$row || $row["email_address"] == '') { statement can you help me with that cos its always returns true.

Comment: Without the database I can't help. Drop a dump to pastebin if it's just test data

Comment: my database has only one table and two fields email_address and password. how do I do drop a dump to pastbin

Comment: I've just updated my code to reflect the new standard and I got it to work, can you improve my code at all. The code you provided didn't quite work can you improve mine. It suppose to return an empty string for a true or false condition in anoher page or webservice page.